# word-wrap feature not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am using the following stylesheet code to achieve word-wrap in the column of a table:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table,td {  
        table-layout: fixed;        
    }
</style>
```

This code works well in firefox and I'm able to achieve word-wrapping but when I tried this in chrome browser, it doesn't work.

Can you please suggest how to get it work in all the browsers (IE, firefox, chrome)

Comment: can you please make a fiddle

Comment: Are you setting and widths for the table or its cells …?

Answer (score 3):

Try it this property to css

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe add the `word-wrap: break-word` property to css

Comment: I have already tried this. It works well in firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: in chrome, you can use word-break: break-word

Comment: @KonstantinKrass many thanks!! you should edit this as the answer as it is 100% correct.