# Cell word-wrap behaves weird in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, word-wrap, tablecell, column-width

Word-wrap doesn't work for the same code in Chrome, but works in Firefox.
Here is the screenshot of what I see in Firefox:

[image]

Widths of columns Country and Hometown is our point of interest.

And here is what I see in Chrome

[image]

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gluten/4t6u32w6/18/show/) with the code.

P.S. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553080/word-wrap-feature-not-working-in-chrome) and utilized `word-break: break-all;` but it looks horribly and [breaks every single word](https://jsfiddle.net/Gluten/wf7a4suy/4/show/).

How can we make proper wrapping in Chrome like on the first screenshot?

Chrome version: 65.0.3325.181 
Firefox version: 59.02 (Linux)

Comment: Simply set a `max-width` on the cell in question to have it 'partially' break a word.

Comment: Okay, with a conjunction of `td:nth-child(n)` it works, but, anyway ,it requires manual calculating of each column width, which is inefficient. Probably you should add this as intermediate answer.